# Put a figure in a page of its own, without counting this page

Tags: floats, page-numbering

I would like to have a float figure on a page of its own. The page should not be numbered and should not add to the page-count (e.g, the page before the figure should be m and the page after the figure should be n+1).

I tried this:

```
\begin{figure}

...

\thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocounter{page}{-1}
\end{figure}
```

The page is sufficiently large so it is indeed placed in its own page. However, the page *before* the figure is unnumbered and not counted, while the page of the figure itself is numbered.

I tried to start with:

```
\begin{figure}[p]
```

but got the same result.

I tried:

```
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
```

This worked, but then I had empty space in the page just before the figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually twofolded:

1. To prevent the page counter from increasing, one can use the `afterpage` package in front if the figure.
2. For controlling the pagestyle of the float page the package `floatpag` provides the `\thisfloatpagestyle{empty}` command.

The `\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.1}` is just for this example to ensure that the figure is placed in its own page. Same for the `lipsum` to generate text.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.1}


\begin{document}

    \lipsum \lipsum

    \afterpage{\addtocounter{page}{-1}}
    \begin{figure}[p!]
        \thisfloatpagestyle{empty}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{figure}

     \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I put \clearpage before the figure, the figure is indeed in a page of its own, but there is empty space in the page before.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Yes,  you're right. I will think about this and see if I can rescue my answer.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi see the edit. Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

A `\clearpage` after the float page is necessary, in my point of view, as well as a `\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}` before the `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[50]


\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{ente}
\addtocounter{page}{-1}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\blindtext[50]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another suggestion using package `afterpage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{afterpage}
%\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\lipsum \lipsum
\afterpage{
  \centering
  \addtocounter{page}{-1}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \parbox[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}{
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    %\captionof{figure}{xxx}
  }
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

You can load `caption` and use `\captionof{figure}{...}` if a caption is needed for this nonfloating picture.